# Let $n\in \mathbb N$. Prove that in $\mathbb{Z}_n$, $(\bar{a}+\bar{b})^2=\bar{a}^2+\bar{2}\bar{a}\bar{b}+\bar{b}^2$

Tags: number-theory

Let $n\in \mathbb N$. Prove that in $\mathbb{Z}_n$, $(\bar{a}+\bar{b})^2=\bar{a}^2+\bar{2}\bar{a}\bar{b}+\bar{b}^2$

How does $(\bar{a}+\bar{b})^2=\bar{a}^2+\bar{2}\bar{a}\bar{b}+\bar{b}^2$ relate to $\mathbb{Z}_3$? Why could I not show that $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$?

Comment: You also do not use that $n$.

Comment: How do I even use the n?

Answer (score 2):

You can. This is because the projection map $\pi: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_n$ is a homomorphism, so for any polynomial $P(a,b)$, $P(\pi(a), \pi(b)) = \pi(P(a,b))$.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using "bar" to denote representative elements in $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

Note that $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$ is an identity in $\mathbb{Z}$.

So it means that if you divide the LHS and the RHS by any integer $n$, the remainders must be equal.

But precisely, $\overline{(a+b)^2}$ is the remainder obtained when $(a+b)^2$ is divided by $n$, and similarly you conclude about the right side.

Also note that $\overline{xy}=\overline{x}\space\overline{y}$ and $\overline{x+y}=\overline{x}+\overline{y}$, and conclusion follows.